# how do I use the arguments of main in C?

Tags: c

I'm using this code to test the entry from the command line when executing the program .. It's  not working. What should I do ???? ?

```
if(argc >1)
    {
        if (argv[1]  == "b" || argv[1]  == "B")
                {b =1;}
        else if (argv[1]  == "h" || argv[1]  == "H")
                { b = 0;}
    }
    else 
        { b =0; }
```

Comment: "It's not working" - I'll be as specific as you were. "Fix it!"

Answer (score 2):

You can not compare c strings using `==` operator. Use [strcmp](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) instead. For example -

```
if ( (0 == strcmp(argv[1], "b") ||  .... )
```

Comment: thank You very much . it worked. It's been a while since i used C.